# C# Textbox with numbers only

Tags: c#, wpf, numbers, masking

I want only numbers to be mathematically processed in textboxes and I use "System.Text.RegularExpressions" for this.

The masking I am using now is `"^ [0-9] + \,? [0-9] * $"`. I cannot enter *negative numbers* in this use.

How can I create a mask that will only support the following number formats.

It's only available for whole numbers everywhere. Unfortunately, I could not find a number format to be mathematically operated.

My Code

```
public static class Masking
{
    
    
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey _maskExpressionPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("MaskExpression",
        typeof(Regex),
        typeof(Masking),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="Mask"/> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Mask",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Masking),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnMaskChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="MaskExpression"/> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskExpressionProperty = _maskExpressionPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mask for a given <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask is to be retrieved.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mask, or <see langword="null"/> if no mask has been set.
    /// </returns>
    public static string GetMask(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        return textBox.GetValue(MaskProperty) as string;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the mask for a given <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask is to be set.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="mask">
    /// The mask to set, or <see langword="null"/> to remove any existing mask from <paramref name="textBox"/>.
    /// </param>
    public static void SetMask(TextBox textBox, string mask)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        textBox.SetValue(MaskProperty, mask);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mask expression for the <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method can be used to retrieve the actual <see cref="Regex"/> instance created as a result of setting the mask on a <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask expression is to be retrieved.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mask expression as an instance of <see cref="Regex"/>, or <see langword="null"/> if no mask has been applied to <paramref name="textBox"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static Regex GetMaskExpression(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        return textBox.GetValue(MaskExpressionProperty) as Regex;
    }

    private static void SetMaskExpression(TextBox textBox, Regex regex)
    {
        textBox.SetValue(_maskExpressionPropertyKey, regex);
    }

    private static void OnMaskChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        var mask = e.NewValue as string;
        textBox.PreviewTextInput -= textBox_PreviewTextInput;
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
        textBox.GotFocus += textBox_GotFocus;
        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(textBox, Pasting);

        if (mask == null)
        {
            textBox.ClearValue(MaskProperty);
            textBox.ClearValue(MaskExpressionProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.SetValue(MaskProperty, mask);
            SetMaskExpression(textBox, new Regex(mask, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
            textBox.PreviewTextInput += textBox_PreviewTextInput;
            textBox.PreviewKeyDown += textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
            textBox.GotFocus += textBox_GotFocus;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(textBox, Pasting);
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Globals.KeyboardActive.IsChecked == true)
        {
            Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(
        ((Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\osk.exe"))));
        }
    }


    private static void textBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, e.Text);

        if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, " ");

            if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }


        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, " ");

            if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            var pastedText = e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
            var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, pastedText);

            if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private static string GetProposedText(TextBox textBox, string newText)
    {
        var text = textBox.Text;

        if (textBox.SelectionStart != -1)
        {
            text = text.Remove(textBox.SelectionStart, textBox.SelectionLength);
        }

        text = text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, newText);

        return text;
    }
}
```

Xaml Code

```
<TextBox Name="Text" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Foreground="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}" Height="25" Width="90"
                     materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="{DynamicResource UnderlineColor}"
                     materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="#244886"
                     AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Elevetion Angle" Margin="172,15,0,0"
                         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.SuffixText="°"
                             b:Masking.Mask="^-?[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]+)?$"
                             LostFocus="textboxsLostFocus"/>
```

Comment: `^-?[0-9]+(\,[0-9]+)?$` - optional minus sign, followed by mandatory integer part (which is one or more digits), followed by optional fractional part (which is comma and one or more digits)

Comment: I cannot put commas with this masking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend regex for this simple task. The performance when using simple string comparison is far better.

Generally you should use `double.TryParse()` to test whether a string is a pure numeric value.

The following example extends `TextBox` and overrides `OnTextInput` to cancel non numeric input. The filter allows a single decimal separator. It's dynamic/customizable as it depends on the current culture's `NumberFormatInfo` when comparing current separator characters or other number signs.

```
class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
  #region Overrides of TextBoxBase

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
  {
    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    if (TryHandleSpecialNonNumericCharacter(e, culture))
    {
      base.OnTextInput(e);
      return;
    }

    // Input is not a special character.
    // Cancel text input if non-numeric.
    e.Handled = !IsInputNumeric(e.Text, culture);

    base.OnTextInput(e);
  }

  private bool IsInputNumeric(string input, IFormatProvider culture) =>
    double.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Number, culture, out _) ;

  private bool TryHandleSpecialNonNumericCharacter(TextCompositionEventArgs inputArgs, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string input = inputArgs.Text;
    switch (input)
    {
      case var _ when input.Equals(culture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase): 
      case var _ when input.Equals(culture.NumberFormat.PositiveSign, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase):
        break;

      // Allow single decimal separator
      case var _ when input.Equals(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase):
        inputArgs.Handled = this.Text.Contains(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  #endregion
}
```

Comment: There is an error in the code. "InvertedValue" is not defined in the ConvertNumericTextToPositive function. and why are you multiplying by -1 for positive value?  Contains cannot take two arguments.

Comment: Value is multiplied by '-1' to invert the positive value: when entering `5` and the press `-`, the number is inverted to `-5`. Alternatively precede the calculation or variable with a `-`. `String.Contains` accepts 2 arguments when using .NET Core, .NET 5 or in general .NET Standard 2.1. I have adjusted the code to comply to .NET Standard 1.0.

Comment: If you don't like this behavior you can remove the first two switch cases.

Comment: I tried your code. But there is no such structure in any user experience. I write the number and then when I press the minus it converts the number to minus. I have not seen such an event in any interface until now. Also I cannot use materialDesign properties. It seems like I have to add all the features to that class. But Thanks for be interested.

Comment: Are you serious? You can remove this behavior, I told you before. You should be smart enough to delete those lines of code. Fact is you have to handle the situation when the user enters negative numbers. You have to make sure only a single minus sign was entered. Don't know about your material design problem. This is a simple TextBox. So material design should be able to theme it too.

Comment: I have deleted those lines for you. Wasn't too difficult.

Comment: Currently the code does not allow "-" to be entered. Previously he was only exhibiting special behavior.

Comment: Now I understand, I will rewrite the controls when the "-" statement is entered. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. If it is fast, I did it directly copy and paste. Thank you for the nice solution. It just prevents me from using the materialDesign features. I will see how to figure it out.

Comment: How did you configure Material Design? 100% that it works. Maybe you want to post your resource dictionary where you have defined the themes?

Comment: Just follow the ["Getting stared"](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) section and then assign the style to the `NumericTextBox`: `<NumericTextBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}"/>`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it does not originate from the start section. It worked directly when the style was set. Fantastic. I was tired, thank you again.